Where can I find a guide on CSON (Coffee Script Object Notation)?
I am familiar with JSON, and I can see some readability benefits of using CSON. However, while I can find all sorts of parsers for CSON, I can’t find a detailed description of the syntax itself.
I understand that it uses indentation rather than braces, and is more forgiving in other respects.
I have checked the CoffeeScript site, Wikipedia (which has all of one paragraph on it), and a lot of web searches.

What exactly are you looking for? Isn’t it just CoffeScript?

@DaveNewton The rules for JSON aren’t exactly the same as for JavaScript object literals. I wouldn’t be surprised if that’s also the case for CSON and CoffeeScript.

It's simply the notation that CoffeeScript (an amazing language, BTW!) uses for declaring objects. You'll find all necessary details on the CoffeeScript website!
